# Getting error while implementing Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

ERROR: local variable t is accessed from within inner class need to be declared final And local variable t1 is accessed from within the class.same with t1.start(); why do I need to declare them final?

```
public class sync {
    public int count = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sync obj = new sync();
        obj.dowork();
        sync obj1 = new sync();
        obj1.dowork1();
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public void dowork() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void dowork1() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
                t1.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got an errant semi-colon in your method declaration: `public static void main(String args[]);{`.  After that, a semi-colon is missing to terminate the line on which you initialize your `obj` variable: `sync obj = new sync()`.

Comment: I mistyped it's not in the actual programme. I edited the above code

Comment: It would help if you used your actual code, or at least code that will compile and run.  As it is, it's difficult to tell what you are trying to do with this code.  The last few lines are also broken.

Answer (score 0):

t and t1 objects are limited to scope of methods, make them member variables. Secondly, method calls and statements are called from inside a method..here t.start() & t1.start() are just floating loose inside class ... Same goes for print statement  it
should also be called from inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you told me really helpful now it's just Showing: System.out.println("count"+count);
Identifier expected plus reach end of file while parsing

Answer (score 0):

Call to start method should be after the threads (t,t1) has been initialized. Currently they are used inside the initialization process.
It should be like this :

```
public void dowork(){
Thread t=new Thread (new Runnable (){
public void run(){
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
count++;}
}});
t.start();
}
```

Also ***count*** should be a static variable, as you cannot refer non-static variable from inside a static main method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class sync {
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sync obj = new sync();
        obj.dowork();
        sync obj1 = new sync();
        obj1.dowork1();
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public void dowork() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void dowork1() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code be like, following think are corrected:

1. You make **count** variable static since it is been access with in static main method.
2. You trying to call Thread.start with in the run method which is wrong, since Thread.start method will call run method.

   ```
   public class sync {
           public static int count = 0;
   ```

   public static void main(String args[]) {
               sync obj = new sync();
               obj.dowork();
               sync obj1 = new sync();
               obj1.dowork1();
               System.out.println(count);
           }

           public void dowork() {
               Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                           count++;
                       }
                   }
               });
               t.start();
           }

           public void dowork1() {
               Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                           count++;
                       }
                   }

               });
               t1.start();
           }
       }